# aiogram 3 проблема с state root:None

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, redis, aiogram-3.x

Я пишу тг бота на aiogram 3. Во время разработки проблем никаких не было.
Когда я разместил бота на сервере и поставил storage=Redis(также у меня есть apscheduler), у меня через какое-то время стейты переходят в None.
И у всех пользователей бот умирает и все начинается заново.
В чем может быть проблема?

На данный момент я поставил StateFilter(None)